# Retrieve certain number from data set in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g, regexp-substr

```
1. <0,0><120.96,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>
2. <0,0><143.64,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>
3. <0,0><125.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>
4. <0,0><127.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>
```

Above is the data set I have in Oracle 10g. I need output as below

```
1. 120.96
2. 143.64
3. 125.5
4. 125.5
```

the output I want is only before `"comma" (120.96)`. I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR but I could not get any output. It will be really helpful if someone could provide effective way to solve this

Comment: _I tried using REGEXP_SUBSTR_ **How?**

Comment: REGEXP_REPACE should work fine here, try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method that first parses out the second element and then gets the first number in it:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(x, '<[^>]*>', 1, 2), '[0-9.]+', 1, 1)
```

Another method just gets the third number in the string:

```
select regexp_substr(x, '[0-9.]+', 1, 3)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff some overrated experienced persons love to down vote

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach without using Regexp.
Find the index of second occurrence of '<'. Then find the second occurrence of ',' use those values in substring.

```
    with
    data as
    (
    select '<0,0><120.96,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' x from dual
    UNION ALL
    select '<0,0><143.64,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' x from dual
    UNION ALL
    select '<0,0><125.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual
    )
    select substr(x, instr(x,'<',1,2)+1, instr(x,',',1,2)- instr(x,'<',1,2)-1)
    from data
```

Approach Using Regexp:
Identify the 2nd occurence of numerical value followed by a comma
Then remove the trailing comma.

```
    with
    data as
    (
    select '<0,0><120.96,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' x from dual
    UNION ALL
    select '<0,0><143.64,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' x from dual
    UNION ALL
    select '<0,0><125.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual
    )
    select 
    trim(TRAILING ',' FROM regexp_substr(x,'[0-9.]+,',1,2))
    from data
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses regexp_substr to get the string contained within the 2nd occurance of a less than sign and a comma:

```
SQL> with tbl(id, str) as (
     select 1, '<0,0><120.96,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual union
     select 2, '<0,0><143.64,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual union
     select 3, '<0,0><125.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>'  from dual union
     select 4, '<0,0><127.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>'  from dual
   )
   select id,
          regexp_substr(str, '<(.*?),', 1, 2, null, 1) value
   from tbl;

        ID VALUE
---------- -------------------------------------------
         1 120.96
         2 143.64
         3 125.5
         4 127.5
```

EDIT: I realized the OP specified 10g and the regexp_substr example I gave used the 6th argument (subgroup) which was added in 11g.  Here is an example using regexp_replace instead which should work with 10g:

```
SQL> with tbl(id, str) as (
        select 1, '<0,0><120.96,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual union
        select 2, '<0,0><143.64,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>' from dual union
        select 3, '<0,0><125.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>'  from dual union
        select 4, '<0,0><127.5,2000><241.92,4000><362.88,INF>'  from dual
      )
      select id,
             regexp_replace(str, '^(.*?)><(.*?),.*$', '\2') value
      from tbl;

        ID VALUE
---------- ----------
         1 120.96
         2 143.64
         3 125.5
         4 127.5

SQL>
```